# How can I automatically asynchronously set a new property of an existing struct after initialization?

Tags: swift, asynchronous

A struct `Item` I am using has a property named `path` which contains a String of the location of an image. I'm trying to make it so that when an instance of `Item` is created, the image will automatically be fetched and set to a new `image` property.

Are extensions the way to go for this? I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
extension Item {
    var image: UIImage {
        if self.path == nil {
            return UIImage(named: "default.png")!
        }
        ASYNC_CALL_HERE {
            // need to do something with the image here
        }
    }
}
```

Or is there a better way?

*Note: `Item` is not my struct.*

Answer (score 0):

First, I should point out that your attempt is trying to do something quite different from what you said you want to do in the first paragraph.

If we go by what you said in the first paragraph, you want a *stored* property that is initialised when `Item` is initialised. Unfortunately, you can't add stored properties in extensions, so you can't use an extension. `Item` is a struct, so you can't subclass it either. The only option I see is to create a wrapper class:

```
class ItemWrapper {
    let item: Item
    var image: UIImage?
    init(<insert parameters of Item.init>) {
        item = Item(<insert parameters of Item.init>)
        if item.path == nil {
            image = UIImage(named: "default.png")!
        } else {
            ASYNC_CALL_HERE { fetchedImage in
                image = fetchedImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, if it doesn't have to be a stored property, we can use a similar approach as the one in your attempt. Rather than fetching the image immediately after `Item` is initialised, we only fetch it when the caller needs it. For this, we could use an extension to add a method called `getImage`. You might want to use a dictionary stored somewhere (or something else) as a cache, to simulate a stored property.

```
func getImage(completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
    guard let path = item.path else {
        completion(UIImage(named: "default.png")!)
        return
    }
    if let image = getImageFromCache(item.path!) {
        completion(image)
        return
    }
    ASYNC_CALL_HERE { fetchedImage in
        completion(fetchedImage)
        storeImageInCache(fetchedImage, path)
    }
}
```